# We received the heret-

Tags: civilization-6

In playing civilization 6, I encountered a leader response that seemed quite puzzling to me. I met another civ (Spain), who was neutral towards me. A few turns after I encountered him, he sends me a trade delegation. Wanting to return the favor, I send one back, and receive a strange response:

> "We received the heret- I mean, your trade delegation. I will be sure to instruct them in our ways."

What does this mean, and what was he trying to say that starts with heret-? I can assume that it would be something I wouldn't want to hear, so is it a hostile or ungrateful response?

Comment: @Ellesedil honestly, not sure

Comment: @Ellesedil on second thought, that seems exactly right, because Spain is a very religious oriented civ, and heretic means a nonreligious dissenter. You should post that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks to me like the leader was going to say "heretics" and caught himself before completing his insul- I mean, clarification. Since you mentioned it was the leader from Spain, this makes sense since they excel at spreading religion.

Comment: No one suspects a Spanish Inquisition!